# my variable from one class isn't populating a variable in another class?

Tags: c#

i'm trying to pull a variable from one class which is a login page to access an sql database and populate the dashboard with the required information. When i'm debugging the first instance in debugging shows the login.UserEmail populated correctly but it doesn't seem to save to a varible in the class?

```
public partial class Dashboard : Form
{   

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]

    private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
        (
        int nLeftRect,
        int nTopRect,
        int nRightRect,
        int nBottomRect,
        int nWidthEllipse,
        int nHeightEllipse
        );

    public string firstName, lastName, fullName, monthlyPayment, amountPayable, interest;
    public string email = LogIn.UserEmail;
    
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnDashboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlNav.Height = btnDashboard.Height;
        pnlNav.Top = btnDashboard.Top;
        pnlNav.Left = btnDashboard.Left;
        btnDashboard.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(46, 51, 73);
    }

    DBAccess objDbAccess = new DBAccess();
    DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();

    public Dashboard()
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine(LogIn.UserEmail);
        Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 25, 25));
        pnlNav.Height = btnDashboard.Height;
        pnlNav.Top = btnDashboard.Top;
        pnlNav.Left = btnDashboard.Left;
        btnDashboard.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(46, 51, 73);
    }

    private void Dashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //string query = "Select * from LoanApplication where Email = '" + LogIn.UserEmail + "'";
        string query = "Select MonthlyPayment, TotalPayable, Interest, ApplicantFirstName, Email from LoanApplication where Email = '" + email + "'";

        objDbAccess.readDatathroughAdapter(query, dtUsers);

        objDbAccess.closeConn();

        monthlyPayment = dtUsers.Rows[0]["MonthlyPayment"].ToString();
        amountPayable = dtUsers.Rows[0]["TotalPayable"].ToString();
        interest = dtUsers.Rows[0]["Interest"].ToString();
        fullName = dtUsers.Rows[0]["ApplicantFirstName"].ToString();
        email = dtUsers.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();

        lblMonthlyPayment.Text = monthlyPayment;
        lblAmountPayable.Text = amountPayable;
        lblInterest.Text = interest;
        lblName.Text = fullName;
        lblEmail.Text = email;
```

Comment: The value of the member variable `email` will be set once only, and that is when `Dashboard` is instantiated.  If the value of `LogIn.UserEmail` changes _after_ that (which I'm guessing it does) then it will not update `email`.

Comment: Another important point: Your SQL is potentially open to SQL-Injection vulnerabilities because it is not parameterised.  I'd suggest following one of the many online guides to protect your database from potential exploits.

Comment: Thanks for the input Martin but how can I save LogIn.UserEmail to email without email showing as null when accessed further down the code? I've tried so many different variations of the code and just cant get it to work

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rest of the code or the purpose of it, but an easy way would seem to be to just set `email` to be `LogIn.UserEmail` later on - `email = LogIn.UserEmail;`.  There may be a case to look again at the design of the code itself though as although that solution is easy, it's not the correct one imo.